# How AutoQuery Parameters work when supplied

Tags: servicestack

I've been reviewing servicestack and the documentation.  In regards to autoquery documentation the pre-autoquery and post auto query design is shown below.  Where the DTO does not include the parameter "BookedAfter".  It is my understanding in a non-Auto Query scenario that a Get would provide these parameters for the obvious query input options.  For Auto Query  I have a few questions.  First, it would appear to me that if you only provide specific parameters (instead of leaving it wide open) that only those would be allowed for filtering (assuming DTO specific fields)?  Is this out of the box or would one need to override the Auto Query implementation?  Similarly with below, the code utilized a custom "BookedAfter" parameter.  Would one override the implementation, map the more specific parameter wording to a DTO field query scenario?  And what would it take to allow additional querying capabilities that came out of the box?  I have not been able to find an example from documentation or the community.

```
[Route("/bookings/search")]
public class SeachBookings : IReturn<SeachBookingsResponse>
{      
    public DateTime BookedAfter { get; set; }
}

[Route("/bookings/search")]
public class SeachBookings : QueryDb<Booking>
{      
 public DateTime BookedAfter { get; set; }
}

// Types
public class Booking
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ShiftId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public int Limit { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Auto Query](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms) parameters simply match the rules in the configured [Implicit Conventions](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#implicit-conventions), it's irrelevant if the property is defined on the DTO or not unless you [restrict it with EnableUntypedQueries=false](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#advantages-of-well-defined-service-contracts) in which case it will only look at the conventions from explicit DTO properties.

Your `BookedAfter` matches the [Implicit Convention](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#implicit-conventions):

```
{"%After%", GreaterThanFormat},
```

You're not limited to the pre-configured conventions and can add/remove your own rules.

Comment: This makes perfect sense.  One additional question, where does the "Booked" portion of BookedAfter map to?  It makes more sense to me if it was StartDateAfter, binding directly to a POCO property.

Comment: @AaronLind Right it would need to match a property in your data model so you’d need to use StartDateAfter in this case querying your Booking data model.